# How to integrate Mapbox SDK with SwiftUI

Tags: swift, mapbox, swiftui

I installed the Mapbox SDK into my project, but I don't understand how to integrate this code snippet with `SwiftUI`.

I created a SwiftUI `View` named `MapView`, where I import the Mapbox Framework.

I try to use the `UIViewRepresentable` protocol, as in Apple's tutorial, but without success.

```swift
import Mapbox

class MapView: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let styleURL = URL(string: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/outdoors-v9")
    let mapView = MGLMapView(frame: view.bounds,
                             styleURL: styleURL)
    mapView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

    mapView.setCenter(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 45.52954,
                                             longitude: -122.72317),
                      zoomLevel: 14, 
                      animated: false)
    view.addSubview(mapView)
  }

}
```

I am new to iOS development, so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What did you try with `UIViewRepresentable` and how didn't it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a working sample on how you can integrate the `MGLMapView` with `SwiftUI`.

When using `UIViewRepresentable` you have to implement two delegates: `makeUIView` that will return your view (in this case `MGLMapView`) and `updateUIView` which will receive the same view type as the one returned in `makeUIView` (again `MGLMapView`).

You can use this to experiment.

Also I recommend you get familiar with the React architecture to understand better the SwiftUI approach.

You can improve this sample by making `ContentView` receive a styleURL, and trying different styles in the preview.

```
import Mapbox
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {

        MapboxViewRepresentation(MGLStyle.streetsStyleURL)

    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
#endif

struct MapboxViewRepresentation : UIViewRepresentable {

    let styleURL: URL

    init(_ styleURL: URL) {
        self.styleURL = styleURL
    }

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<MapboxViewRepresentation>) -> MGLMapView {
        let mapView = MGLMapView(frame: .zero, styleURL: styleURL)

        return mapView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: MGLMapView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<MapboxViewRepresentation>) {

    }


}
```

**UPDATE**: Here is the official guide on how to integrate Mapbox with SwiftUI https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/ios-swiftui/

Comment: Thank you! It works exactly as expect! :) I will look more closely to your code to be sure I understand it properly.

Comment: Official guide is no more available... What should we do?