# Blank Map with Mapbox and SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, mapbox

I try to use Mapbox with SwiftUI.

I applied this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56551675/5653544 and also followed the [mapbox tutorial](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/ios-swiftui/).

So I have a MapView.swift view:

```
import SwiftUI
import Mapbox

extension MGLPointAnnotation {
    convenience init(title: String, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        self.init()
        self.title = title
        self.coordinate = coordinate
    }
}

struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var annotations: [MGLPointAnnotation]

    private let mapView: MGLMapView = MGLMapView(frame: .zero, styleURL: MGLStyle.streetsStyleURL)

    // MARK: - Configuring UIViewRepresentable protocol

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<MapView>) -> MGLMapView {
        mapView.delegate = context.coordinator
        return mapView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: MGLMapView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<MapView>) {
        updateAnnotations()
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> MapView.Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    // MARK: - Configuring MGLMapView

    func styleURL(_ styleURL: URL) -> MapView {
        mapView.styleURL = styleURL
        return self
    }

    func centerCoordinate(_ centerCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> MapView {
        mapView.centerCoordinate = centerCoordinate
        return self
    }

    func zoomLevel(_ zoomLevel: Double) -> MapView {
        mapView.zoomLevel = zoomLevel
        return self
    }

    private func updateAnnotations() {
        if let currentAnnotations = mapView.annotations {
            mapView.removeAnnotations(currentAnnotations)
        }
        mapView.addAnnotations(annotations)
    }

    // MARK: - Implementing MGLMapViewDelegate

    final class Coordinator: NSObject, MGLMapViewDelegate {
        var control: MapView

        init(_ control: MapView) {
            self.control = control
        }

        func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, didFinishLoading style: MGLStyle) {

            let coordinates = [
                CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.791329, longitude: -122.396906),
                CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.791591, longitude: -122.396566),
                CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.791147, longitude: -122.396009),
                CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.790883, longitude: -122.396349),
                CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.791329, longitude: -122.396906),
            ]

            let buildingFeature = MGLPolygonFeature(coordinates: coordinates, count: 5)
            let shapeSource = MGLShapeSource(identifier: "buildingSource", features: [buildingFeature], options: nil)
            mapView.style?.addSource(shapeSource)

            let fillLayer = MGLFillStyleLayer(identifier: "buildingFillLayer", source: shapeSource)
            fillLayer.fillColor = NSExpression(forConstantValue: UIColor.blue)
            fillLayer.fillOpacity = NSExpression(forConstantValue: 0.5)

            mapView.style?.addLayer(fillLayer)

        }

        func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, viewFor annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> MGLAnnotationView? {
            return nil
        }

        func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, annotationCanShowCallout annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> Bool {
            return true
        }

    }

}
```

and my ContentView.swift calling the MapView:

```
import SwiftUI
import Mapbox

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var annotations: [MGLPointAnnotation] = [
        MGLPointAnnotation(title: "Mapbox", coordinate: .init(latitude: 37.791434, longitude: -122.396267))
    ]

    var body: some View {
        MapView(annotations: $annotations).centerCoordinate(.init(latitude: 37.791293, longitude: -122.396324)).zoomLevel(16)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

I also created a ~/.mapbox file with a mapbox token that I get with my mapbox account. But I have a blank map:

[image]

When I download and run the [mapbox example](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-maps-swiftui-demo), it works fine so I think it's not due to my Xcode version. Does anyone have a clue of why I can't load the map when I create the project by myself ?

Xcode version: 11.3

Mapbox version: 5.3.0

Comment: could you provide your implementation for Mapbox (code)?

Comment: Have you set your Mapbox `MGLMapboxAccessToken` in your `AppDelegate` or in your `info.plist`?

Comment: I reissued my post to give you more information about my implementation for Mapbox and how I set Mapbox token.
I didn't set the token in MGLMapboxAccessToken or in the info.plist but I wrote it in a ~/.mapbox file because an error said to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set your `MGLMapboxAccessToken` in Info.plist.

Comment: Thank you it works. 
The [mapbox demo](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-maps-swiftui-demo) has an insert_access_token.sh script that manage token on the root directory, that's why I was lost.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I should create a new ask for that but I had the same issue and I also had the `MGLMapboxAccessToken` in `Info.plist` (as proposed by @andrewcar).

In my case I was facing that issue when the app was sent to the background and then to the foreground.

I fixed it by adding a observer to the `UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification` notification and performing a unappreciable zoom change:

In `viewDidLoad` I added:

```
let becomeActiveNotification = NotificationCenter.default
becomeActiveNotification.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(didBecomeActiveNotification), name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
```

Then I implemented `didBecomeActiveNotification` like that:

```
@objc func didBecomeActiveNotification() {
    self.mapView.setZoomLevel(14, animated: false)
    self.mapView.setZoomLevel(15, animated: false) // 15 is my desired zoom level
}
```

I hope it helps somebody, I was almost unable to find an answer for my issue.